# Does this FASTQ data contain single or paired end calls?

Tags: fastq

I have this fastq data from GEO:

```
zcat SRR1658526.fastq.gz | head -n 20
@SRR1658526.1 HWI-ST398:296:C1MP4ACXX:1:1101:1093:2094 length=102
GATCTCTATTACTTTTTGAAGGATTNNNNNNNNNNAANTTTTGAATCANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
+SRR1658526.1 HWI-ST398:296:C1MP4ACXX:1:1101:1093:2094 length=102
@<@FFDFDHHFHHIIIIGHBGGGIG##########10#0:BGDDHHII######################################################
@SRR1658526.2 HWI-ST398:296:C1MP4ACXX:1:1101:1167:2107 length=102
ATAATATTGTAGATATAAATGTTATCTAATCTTATCTGATCAGCTTGCTNNATANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNACNTATGNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCC
+SRR1658526.2 HWI-ST398:296:C1MP4ACXX:1:1101:1167:2107 length=102
CCCFFFFFHHFHHJJIIIIJIJJHJHJJJJIJJIJJJJIJHIJJJJGII#####################################################
```

It is supposed to be paired-end sequences. Is the prefix `@` and `+` are the R1 and R2? What's the convention here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Entries in a fastq file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format) occupy 4 lines each and R1 and R2 are typically in different files. Since that [SRA project is 2x51](https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/?run=SRR1658525) you seem to have run `fastq-dump` without the `--split-3` option, so both R1 and R2 are merged together. Make your life easier and never use SRA, but instead just download the individual files from ENA.

Comment: what's ENA? and how what would be the right `fastq-dump` command?

Comment: ENA is the European Nucleotide Archive. Don't use fastq-dump, don't use SRA at all.

Comment: What would be the equivalent command?

Comment: wget or curl or just right clicking on the web interface and selecting save.

Comment: I see, so ENA is a European mirror of GEO?

Comment: Use aspera, just as with SRA.

Comment: the link will be here: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/view/SRR1658526

Answer (score 2):

The data shown in the fastq files are paired end data.

In fastQ files @ and + do not correspond to R1 and R2.

The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format) for fastq files describe the following conventions:

> A FASTQ file normally uses four lines per sequence.
>
> ```
> Line 1 begins with a '@' character and is followed by a sequence identifier and an optional description (like a FASTA title line).
> Line 2 is the raw sequence letters.
> Line 3 begins with a '+' character and is optionally followed by the same sequence identifier (and any description) again.
> Line 4 encodes the quality values for the sequence in Line 2, and must contain the same number of symbols as letters in the sequence.
> ```

**When using fastq-dump
".1" and ".2" stand for read suffices assuming u used the -I flag.**

In this case you can see that R1 (".1") and R2 (".2") are within the same file.